# Issue with CURL cookies

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I am trying to fetch a webpage through CURL but I'm having some issues with the cookies. When I request a webpage x, it returns:

```
Added cookie cp1c90179ecce957ca733f28fde5fa5227cdaeffb9" for domain xx.org, path http://www.xx.org/, expire 1369549265 
Set-Cookie: cp=1c90179ecce957ca733f28fde5fa5227cdaeffb9; expires=Sun, 26-May-2013 06:21:05 GMT; path=http://www.xx.org/; domain=xx.org
```

therefor the cookie file looks like:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.xx.org TRUE    /   FALSE   1577145000  __cfduid    >d144cbf7cd1c98a83e3683debb97fba9c1369548965
.xx.org TRUE    http://www.xx.org/  FALSE   1369549265  cp  >1c90179ecce957ca733f28fde5fa5227cdaeffb9
```

(The first cookie you see here was set previously by another page i requested on that domain)

The problem is when I request any other page within the website, the cookie is never sent by curl, however it is sent by any other browser and i assume its because of the path it sends is the full domain instead of `/`.

Is there any way to make curl send that cookie without having to modify the cookie file?